# Unable to pickle complete dataset

Tags: python, tensorflow, pickle

I am currently working on an assignment in the Udacity Deep Learning Course which follows [this IPython Notebook](https://github.com/tensorflow/tensorflow/blob/master/tensorflow/examples/udacity/1_notmnist.ipynb). When  I try to pickle the datasets (function `maybe_pickle`), it is able to pickle up to the folder "F", but no further. This is the output I am getting.

```
['././notMNIST_large/A', '././notMNIST_large/B', '././notMNIST_large/C', '././notMNIST_large/D', '././notMNIST_large/E', '././notMNIST_large/F', '././notMNIST_large/G', '././notMNIST_large/H', '././notMNIST_large/I', '././notMNIST_large/J']
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/A.pickle
././notMNIST_large/A
Could not read  ././notMNIST_large/A/Um9tYW5hIEJvbGQucGZi.png  :  cannot identify image file '././notMNIST_large/A/Um9tYW5hIEJvbGQucGZi.png' 
Skipping this image.
Could not read  ././notMNIST_large/A/RnJlaWdodERpc3BCb29rSXRhbGljLnR0Zg==.png  :  cannot identify image file '././notMNIST_large/A/RnJlaWdodERpc3BCb29rSXRhbGljLnR0Zg==.png' 
Skipping this image.
Could not read  ././notMNIST_large/A/SG90IE11c3RhcmQgQlROIFBvc3Rlci50dGY=.png  :  cannot identify image file '././notMNIST_large/A/SG90IE11c3RhcmQgQlROIFBvc3Rlci50dGY=.png' 
Skipping this image.
Full dataset tensor:  (52909, 28, 28)
Mean:  -0.12825
Standard Deviation:  0.443121
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/B.pickle
././notMNIST_large/B
Could not read  ././notMNIST_large/B/TmlraXNFRi1TZW1pQm9sZEl0YWxpYy5vdGY=.png  :  cannot identify image file '././notMNIST_large/B/TmlraXNFRi1TZW1pQm9sZEl0YWxpYy5vdGY=.png' 
Skipping this image.
Full dataset tensor:  (52911, 28, 28)
Mean:  -0.00756303
Standard Deviation:  0.454492
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/C.pickle
././notMNIST_large/C
Full dataset tensor:  (52912, 28, 28)
Mean:  -0.142258
Standard Deviation:  0.439806
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/D.pickle
././notMNIST_large/D
Could not read  ././notMNIST_large/D/VHJhbnNpdCBCb2xkLnR0Zg==.png  :  cannot identify image file '././notMNIST_large/D/VHJhbnNpdCBCb2xkLnR0Zg==.png' 
Skipping this image.
Full dataset tensor:  (52911, 28, 28)
Mean:  -0.0573678
Standard Deviation:  0.455647
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/E.pickle
././notMNIST_large/E
Full dataset tensor:  (52912, 28, 28)
Mean:  -0.0698991
Standard Deviation:  0.452942
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/F.pickle
././notMNIST_large/F
Full dataset tensor:  (52912, 28, 28)
Mean:  -0.125583
Standard Deviation:  0.447089
Pickling ././notMNIST_large/G.pickle
././notMNIST_large/G
```

Nothing happens after this, i.e. it never terminates. Any ideas on how to proceed? I have even tried terminating the program and running it again but there has been no progress.

Comment: do you import Image in your code? and show that line

Comment: Yes I did. Does it affect the pickling process? Because I am able to pickle the images in 6/10 folders.

Comment: try this `from PIL import Image`. If works I'll post as answer

Comment: I ran it again. It skips the ones that are already pickled (as in the tutorial) but I was only able to pickle one more folder. The same issue arises after that.